# How do I access the properties in every instance of a class whithin another class?

Tags: javascript, oop

I need to access the values of every instance of a class, and compare them.

So first, I get my properties:

```
class One {
    constructor(){
        this.properties = new Properties();
    }
}
```

Then, I need to read every instance that is created (in any number) and use them as arguments:

```
class Two {
    check(){
        if (/* arguments that contain info on all instances of class One */) {
            // code
        }
    }
}
```

Then I need to create instances of class Two, and call the `check()` function.

Comment: You never should need to get "*all instances that were ever created*". Always collect the particular instances that you were creating explicitly in a list, then pass that to your method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static property on your `class One` in order to store the instances when you call it with new, and later you call the static property to get an array of all instances, take a look:

```
// just to complement the example
class Properties {
  name
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }
}

class One {
    // here is the static property where you will store the instance
    static allInstances = [];
    properties
    constructor(name){
      this.properties = new Properties(name);

      // here you will store the class instance
      // every time it's created
      One.allInstances.push(this)
    }
}

const instance1 = new One("instance1")
const instance2 = new One("instance2")
const instance3 = new One("instance3")

console.log(One.allInstances)
// (3) [_One {...}, _One {...}, _One {...}]

class Two {
  constructor() {}

  check(instanceNames){
    // here I'm logging the name of each instance
    instanceNames.forEach(instance => 
      console.log(instance.properties.name))
  }
}

const instanceOfTwo = new Two()

// pass the array of all instances with One.allInstances
instanceOfTwo.check(One.allInstances)
```

See the [complete example](https://playcode.io/893779), to know more about static methods and properties [check this out](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static).